# What statistical analysis do i deploy? if i have 100 survey respondents from a population of 1000

Tags: statistical-significance, sampling, ordinal-data, likert

And i obtained these responses by a random mechanism. (My study sample is a random sample from my population.) And i have likert data. Do i just report it with a bar chart, and maybe a frequency table. There is no way investigating the likelihood of this data being a true reflection of the population? is there?

---

what about reporting the interquartile range for my ordinal data - is that a common thing to do, do you write IQR=       ?
can i do that with that likert data?

Comment: Please comment - i know you know the answer!! :)      should i make some comment on the variance in the data? like they do with election polling - that margin of error they refer to?

Comment: I think you have largely answered your own question, though the interquartile range seems unnecessary.  You would have to do individual bar charts for each question in your survey and could provide confidence intervals for each bar if you wish.